# Why Adobe illustrator expand appearances creates double path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

I need convert 3D rotate effect to shape in Ai.

[image]

[image]

[image]

after effect, i try to convert it by **Object > Expand appearances**

but final shape has double path!
I just need one shape, How can i Achive it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the 3D rotate to a shape with a stroke and no fill, do it to a shape just with fill; Expand Appearance and apply the stroke.

The final shape is inside a clipping mask, delete it selecting it with the Direct Selection tool.

[image: Expand]

The reason why Illustrator does this is because when expanding it does it with all the effects applied and in this case, the stroke is one more element to expand.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your object has a **stroke** applied.

If the "N" was merely a shape with a **fill** and no stroke, you would expand to a single path with a fill.

When you expand strokes, it creates a *compound shape* with a fill and a counter (hole). Strokes don't expand to strokes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it does it, a workaround that I do is ungroup them, select one and then hit delete.

When dealing with a bunch of shapes, I do the same steps, but then hit **Select → Same** and delete. I then select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>D</kbd> for default appearance.